# Cassandra querying without full primary key

Tags: index, cassandra

As far as I understand there are no secondary indices with multiple columns, only single columns.

So how do I solve the index problem I'm having? This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logstv.messages (
    timestamp timestamp,
    channelid bigint,
    userid bigint,
    message text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((channelid, timestamp), userid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);
```

But this is the error currently:
`Missing CLUSTERING ORDER for column userid`

**I want these things:**

- SELECT WHERE with channelid, userid, timestamp with an order by timestamp and limit
- SELECT WHERE with channelid, timestamp with an order by timestamp and limit

Is this possible?

The only option I currently see is setting `timestamp` as the primary key and then sorting through the rest in my software, which seems very expensive. Or having 2 tables for my data which i want to very much avoid because the data will grow very fast and get big.

**Example queries:**

```
SELECT message, timestamp
        FROM logstv.messages 
        WHERE userid = ? 
        AND channelid = ? 
        AND timestamp >= ? 
        AND timestamp <= ?
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 100;

SELECT message, timestamp
        FROM logstv.messages 
        WHERE channelid = ? 
        AND timestamp >= ? 
        AND timestamp <= ?
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: The general solution is to duplicate the data in another table with a different key. Indexes are possible but very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, It is possible with '**ALLOW FILTERING**' option. **BUT NOT ADVISABLE** (well explained in this [link](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2)). Schema design in Cassandra is majorly Query Specific (i.e) design your schema so that it is able to answer a query.

If you want to query on different attributes, go for individual schemas for each one.

Comment: Is it maybe possible without ALLOW FILTERING; but only supporting WHERE `timestamp + channelid` and `timestamp + userid + channelid` ? Leaving out some queries?

Comment: @gempir as per your model in the question, you can query only based on channel.id + user.id /// or /// channel.id+user.id+timestamp and nothing more than that .

Comment: The schema is changeable. I just want to avoid storing messages twice in 2 tables

Comment: What kind of queries do you want to apply on logstv.messages?

Comment: 2 kind something with channelid, timestamp and userid AND a query with just channelid and timestamp

Comment: Then your primary key should be PRIMARY KEY ((channelid,timestamp),userid) (or) PRIMARY KEY ((channelid),timestamp,userid).

Comment: How do the 2 versions differ? Should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: @gempir, first one will have (channelid,timestamp) as partition key and second one only (channelid) as partion key. Choose the best one based on the nature of your data to prevent hot-spot

Comment: Ok but then I can't ORDER BY timestamp anymore correct?

Comment: as per second model you can do that but not with first one

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to get it working. I've updated the the post with the new TABLE but it won't even create (error below). Also I've added 2 example queries which don't really work either (without the clustering order by in table)

Comment: better go though cql queries limitations from datastax site . it seems like improper design with what cassandra can do

Comment: I think this will help you, [link] (https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to solve this for Cassandra is to model two separate tables, one to support each query.

For this query:

```
SELECT message, timestamp
FROM logstv.messages 
WHERE userid = ? 
AND channelid = ? 
AND timestamp >= ? 
AND timestamp <= ?
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

...this table should work:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logstv.messages (
    timestamp timestamp,
    channelid bigint,
    userid bigint,
    message text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((channelid), userid, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (userid ASC, timestamp DESC);
```

The idea here, is that `timestamp` has to be the last clustering column in order for you to be able to specify a range condition on it.

For this query:

```
SELECT message, timestamp
FROM logstv.messages 
WHERE channelid = ? 
AND timestamp >= ? 
AND timestamp <= ?
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

I'd build a query table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logstv.messages_by_channelid (
    timestamp timestamp,
    channelid bigint,
    userid bigint,
    message text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((channelid), timestamp, userid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC, userid ASC);
```

Same approach, but `userid` and `timestamp` should be flipped.

The only potential problem I see, is that depending on how many messages are received per-channel, you may want to partition on a date component...just not `timestamp`.  Not sure how many messages this system receives, but perhaps month would work?

Ex:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((channelid, month), timestamp, userid)
```

You would then have to specify the month of the messages that you would like to get back.  Another time component may be more appropriate, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the need to put timestamp into the partition key.
You can check out [partitioning in Cassandra](https://academy.datastax.com/units/2206-partitioning-storage-structure-practical-application-data-modeling-apache-cassandra?resource=ds220)

In case you want to query a column that is not in your current table's primary key you have the Materialized View to do so for ONE other column (per view).
[Cassandra 3.0](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2015/06/new-cassandra-30-materialized-views)